# High response time in Gatling tests

Tags: rest, performance-testing, gatling, apachebench, scala-gatling

I have a problem with Gatling and an API Response time. I want to test the performance (response time) of and endpoint with a certain number of users (200 in the examples).

I have an endpoint in https://my-remote-machine/rest/v1/auth-token to get a valid token performing a POST operation with credentials.

### Results

**Apache benchmark**

Running the next command:

`ab -T 'application/json' -n 200 -c 200 -p creds https://my-remote-machine/rest/v1/auth-token`

I get the next response times:

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      101  112  75.4    104    1139
Processing:    66   85  79.6     73    1036
Waiting:       66   85  79.6     73    1035
Total:        169  197 111.8    177    1209


Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    177
  66%    180
  75%    185
  80%    188
  90%    196
  95%    236
  98%    418
  99%   1155
 100%   1209 (longest request)
```

Between **169ms** and **1209ms**

But when I do it with Gatling, the response time is super high and I don't know why is this happening. (Tests were executed in local and in a Jenkins pipeline in the same vShpere host, less network latency and same results)

### Gatling code

```
val httpProtocol = http.baseUrl("https://my-remote-machine/rest/v1/")

val scn = scenario(scenarioName)
  .exec(
    http("my-auth-requests")
      .post("auth-token")
      .body(StringBody("{ \"username\":\"admin\", \"password\":\"mypassword\" }"))
      .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .check(status.is(200))

setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(numberOfUsers))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

And the results:

```
================================================================================
---- Global Information --------------------------------------------------------
> request count                                        200 (OK=200    KO=0     )
> min response time                                    365 (OK=365    KO=-     )
> max response time                                   3322 (OK=3322   KO=-     )
> mean response time                                  2359 (OK=2359   KO=-     )
> std deviation                                        750 (OK=750    KO=-     )
> response time 50th percentile                       2544 (OK=2544   KO=-     )
> response time 75th percentile                       2946 (OK=2946   KO=-     )
> response time 95th percentile                       3260 (OK=3260   KO=-     )
> response time 99th percentile                       3306 (OK=3306   KO=-     )
> mean requests/sec                                     50 (OK=50     KO=-     )
---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------
> t < 800 ms                                            12 (  6%)
> 800 ms < t < 1200 ms                                  10 (  5%)
> t > 1200 ms                                          178 ( 89%)
> failed                                                 0 (  0%)
================================================================================
```

Between **365ms** and **3322ms** which is way higher than with Apache Benchmark

I've repeated the tests lots of times and always the same results.

Any clue?

Comment: aren't you hitting different endpoints? (https://my-remote-machine/telemetry/v1/auth-token vs https://my-remote-machine/rest/v1/my-auth-requests)

Comment: It was a matter of not put the real endpoint, edited. Anyway I think your assesment is not correct since the endpoint is what it goes in the `post()` not in the `http()`. You can check it in the Gatling doc (https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request#method-and-url). Thanks for the check anyway :)